# Get all of the instance names from a many to many object?

Tags: database, django

I tried querying the Db with this bit of code:

```
Makesite.objects.values_list('ref_id', flat =True)
```

and it returned [1,2,None]. Which I found to be moderately confusing. I assumed that python saved the instances by their own names and not numbers that it just assigns to them. Any help with the code or an explanation to why python saves them as numbers and not their names would be awesome thanks.

In models.py

```
class Makesite(models.Model):
    sitename = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique = True) 
    siteinfo = models.ManyToManyField(Siteinfo)
    ref_id = models.ManyToManyField(RefID)
    report = models.ManyToManyField(Report)
```

Comment: How does `Makesite` look like. What is `sitename` field?

Comment: i threw some models code in there hopefully thats what you were looking for

Comment: also i copied the wrong code editted the variable name

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't save m2m by their "names". It uses their primary keys (in your case - integers). You can check it, by viewing your DB tables.

When you just use something like `makesite.sitename` Django makes anither query to fetch sitename instance.

But when you use `values_list` you don't want extra queries or joins, that's why Django returns data **from a single table**. And all that it can get form there is a primary key.

If you want to optimize your related queries take a look at [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) / [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) methods or use caching.

Comment: Okay. So how does it know what instance to use when I use code like this? `Makesite.objects.get(sitename=site).ref_id.values_list('refid',flat=True)`. where site is the name of the instance.

Comment: @city It first does a join, then returns of all the `refid`'s of joined relation. [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) is a cool tool for examining SQL queries made by Django. It will make it clearer.

Comment: alright. Is there a way that I can turn these primary keys into the instance names?

Comment: @city `Makesite.objects.get(sitename=site).ref_id.all()`

Comment: already tried that. only returns the one that = site. with more detail it reutrns what it contains. not what the name of it is. so like all of its contents realitve to what site equals

Comment: @city And what do you want to get? A list of `RefID` instances for each `Makesite` isntance?

Comment: Umm. well yeah. I got the list I was looking for with this.. `Makesite.objects.values_list('sitename',flat=True)` Kinda dumb it was that easily but I guess one last question would be how would I get a list of what the sitename are (the instance they are saved under) if I didn't have a separate field for the names? so say i put the sitename within ref_id and saved 3 different instances as bird, plane and bike. how could I get a list of [bird,plane,bike] from that?